# WSO2 token generation, /oauth2/token service failing after 20th request been hit

Tags: post, oauth-2.0, wso2, access-token, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 for token generation. By using this console: https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp

I am calling http://localhost:9763**/oauth2/token** service by passing required parameters
`<{username=[], password=[], grant_type=[password], client_id=[], client_secret=[], scope=[]},[Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]>` after 20th request its failing and giving below error.

> {ErrorMessage: I/O error on POST request for "http://192.168.200.83:9763/oauth2/token": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.}

How can I increase the number of requests to be served from 20 to 50 or more?

Comment: Can you attach the full stack trace?

Comment: What do you mean by 20th request? is it the 20th concurrent request or just the 20th request if its the second case you may need to add the stacktrace of the identity sever to the question as well